# Select MySQL with double restrict

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I have two tables and I would like select in the first one only the reports that aren't in the second one which have id_user='N', all by foreign key id (table1.id, filter_table1.id_table1).

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM table1, filter_table1 
WHERE table1.id!=(SELECT id_table1 FROM filter_table1 WHERE id_user='1')
```

Comment: whats problem in above query?

Comment: You have to provide a join condition on your two tables. Without your table schema or more info, we can't really help much really. Also, just save yourself some trouble and use explicit joins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I rather do using `LEFT JOIN` than `NOT IN`

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    table1 a
        LEFT JOIN filter_table1 b
            ON  a.ID = b.id_table1 AND
                b.id_user = 1
WHERE   b.id_table1 IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1
WHERE table1.id NOT IN (SELECT id_table1 FROM filter_table1 WHERE id_user='1')
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need a join in the above query -- just use what's known as a [correlated subquery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery):

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM table1 t1
WHERE t1.id NOT IN (
  SELECT id_table1 
  FROM filter_table1 
  WHERE id_user = '1' AND t1.id = filter_table1.id_table1
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1, filter_table1 
WHERE table1.id NOT IN (SELECT id_table1 FROM filter_table1 WHERE id_user='1')
```